# How to check if sequence exists

Tags: php, numbers, escaping, sequence

I have different sequences of numbers inside my db, (grouped by session and each number in a row).

For example:
Sequence 1: 1,2,3,4,5
Sequence 2: 1,1,2,5,4,5,3

I need to find the sequence 4,5 that is on sequence 1 and 2

I need to use that method to find in a roulette game the frequency of numbers.

Important: the script should check every sequence numbers and check each number is repeat after another on other sequence.

Like 4 and 5 on both sequence above

Comment: What's special about "4,5"? Why doesn't "1,2" qualify?

Comment: Anything special, is like an easy example. I said i will use for numbers of roulette game, so i need to find SAME sequences (if there). Another example: numbers 32,35, i need to know if on another sequence there are these numbers 32,35) in this exactly position, so 32 before 35